# In the Restaurant Reviews example how do I find which Restaurant

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been reading this extremely useful blog post about`collectionGroup` - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html.

I have one question.

Say, as per the example, I want to find all the reviews written by me. No problem I can do that with `collectionGroup`. But now as I read each review, how do I know which restaurant it is about.

I'm guessing I would include some summary information about the restaurant in the `review` document.

Is this the best approach or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the document snapshot for a review, you can get its document reference, and then find its parent restaurant document by walking up the parent chain.

So in the JavaScript example from the blog:

```js
myReviews.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
    const docRef = docSnapshot.ref;
    const collectionRef = docRef.parent;
    const parentRef = collectionRef.parent; // <-- restaurant document reference
    const parentId = parentRef.id; // <-- restaurant ID
  })
})
```